# Storing in browsers session storage vs storing in in-memory variable

Tags: javascript, html, web-storage

I want to cache a big object coming from a web api response in java script.
I have two options either to store it in browsers session storage or I can have some variable hold the response. I am aware that session storage has some advantage of persisting till the session is closed, but apart from that is there any more benefits of using session storage(such as effect on memory of browser)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends upon if you need to support browsing via iPhone. See https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/01/23/ios-private-browsing-localstorage/ for iPhone private browsing woes with local storage, namely that safari reports DOM exception 22, storage quota exceeded.

Either way, your local storage usage needs to pass via a variable anyway.

You could reduce Ajax requests by storing in session storage, I guess, with a fallback that performs the Ajax request every page load if the browser doesn't support local storage or the value isn't present.